# Python & Ubuntu 14.04 \ removing a python version installed manually

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pyqt4, uninstallation

I installed manually a 2.7.8 python on Ubuntu 14.04, not realizing a 2.7.6 was already shipped with Ubuntu (I used this how-to, changing the python version to 2.7.8: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu)

When I list the python versions I have on my system, here is what is output.

```
pierre@pierre-VirtualBox:~/Téléchargements$ sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
/home/pierre/Téléchargements/Python-2.7.8/python: Python 2.7.8
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
/usr/bin/python3.4: Python 3.4.0
/usr/bin/python3.4m: Python 3.4.0
/usr/local/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.8
```

I installed then PyQt4 with Synaptic, and when I check if it's correctly installed, it seems it isn't.

```
pierre@pierre-VirtualBox:~/Téléchargements$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jan 14 2015, 18:34:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

I need PyQt4 for another program, but this one doesn't detect PyQt4, while synaptic tells me PyQt4 is installed.

I believe I have messed up with my python versions:

- on one hand I think that python 2.7.8 became the default python & is recognized by this other programm I want to install (its installation is "manual")
- on the other hand, the "default" python version for synaptic seems to be 2.7.5 & PyQt4 is installed for this one only

Hence, I would like to remove python 2.7.8.
Please, could someone point me how to do that?

I thank you very much for your help.
Best regards,

Pierre

Comment: Since you installed it using a guide from askUbuntu, why don't you ask how to uninstall it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't provide an `uninstall` target in the Makefile it generates, so you will have to remove the files manually. This shouldn't be too difficult in your case, though, because you installed it under `/usr/local`.

A typical python2.7 installation will put all the files in these locations:

```
    /usr/local/include/python2.7
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
    /usr/local/share/man/man.1
    /usr/local/bin
```

If you examine these directories in a file-manager, you can readily to see what has been recently added. The output from the interactive session shown in your question shows a compile date of `Jan 14 2015, 18:34:11` - so the installed files will all have timestamps a few minutes after that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I removed everything by hand as you hinted, and recovered the correct python distribution provided by Ubuntu. Thanks!